# Opening Firefox on second display at startup

Tags: display, monitor

I have attached two monitos: 1 dvi (primary) 1 HDMI. I have added this at startup app list to load Firefox at bootup:

```
firefox -P TV -url "http://mylocaldom.com" -no-remote
```

This is the output of `xrandr --query`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1366x768+0+1 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768       59.8*+
   1280x720       60.0
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0
   832x624        74.6
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3
   640x480        75.0     72.8     60.0
   720x400        70.1
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm
   1920x1080      50.0 +   60.0*    59.9     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0
   1280x1024      60.0
   1366x768       59.8
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9
   1440x576i      50.1
   1024x768       60.0
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1
   800x600        60.3
   720x576        50.0
   720x480        60.0     59.9
   640x480        60.0     59.9     59.9
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I want to open Firefox on the second screen (HDMI3) at bootup. Setting display vairbale as 0.1 says diplay 0.1 not found. So, how can I get Firefox open on the second monitor at startup?

Comment: There's a program called [`devilspie`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/devilspie.1.html) which might be of use. I haven't used it so I can't offer any help.